# How do I determine a number of bins from discretize function in R

Tags: r, arules

it seems like a very straight forward thing to do but I am struggling.

I'm currently trying to determine a number of bins in R by using discretize function.

```
df$group = discretize(df$num_var, ???)
```

Could someone please help?
Much appreciated in advance.

Thanks

Comment: You should tell us where the function `discretize()` comes from since it is not in base R. If it is from the `arules` package the second argument is `method=`, how the groups should be defined, not `breaks=`, the number of groups. The function provides several methods (`?discretize`). There are several methods of deciding the number of groups. The functions `nclass.Sturges`, `nclass.scott`, and `nclass.FD` implement three of them. Look up their manual page, `?nclassStugess`, to see which one seems most appropriate to your data or your research question.

Comment: @dcarlson thanks for the post. I'll take a note of mentioning the package the function falls under in the future. Although I did tag the name of the package in the post. Its was "breaks" argument I was after! Thanks heaps for your input.